# What is wrong with my RNN-LSTM model?

Tags: python, lstm

I have built an RNN-LSTM where I try to forecast time-series on temperature. I have read this: https://machinelearningmastery.com/diagnose-overfitting-underfitting-lstm-models/ but my problem does not belong to something among the examples that this guy describes. What I get is this:

```
Epoch 1/20
14154/14154 - 21s - loss: 0.0024 - val_loss: 0.0047 - 21s/epoch - 1ms/step
Epoch 2/20
14154/14154 - 25s - loss: 3.2382e-04 - val_loss: 0.0040 - 25s/epoch - 2ms/step
Epoch 3/20
14154/14154 - 25s - loss: 3.1871e-04 - val_loss: 0.0036 - 25s/epoch - 2ms/step
Epoch 4/20
14154/14154 - 19s - loss: 3.1318e-04 - val_loss: 0.0027 - 19s/epoch - 1ms/step
Epoch 5/20
14154/14154 - 20s - loss: 3.2118e-04 - val_loss: 0.0035 - 20s/epoch - 1ms/step
Epoch 6/20
14154/14154 - 19s - loss: 3.1025e-04 - val_loss: 0.0050 - 19s/epoch - 1ms/step
Epoch 7/20
14154/14154 - 19s - loss: 3.1458e-04 - val_loss: 0.0029 - 19s/epoch - 1ms/step
Epoch 8/20
14154/14154 - 19s - loss: 3.2007e-04 - val_loss: 0.0034 - 19s/epoch - 1ms/step
Epoch 9/20
14154/14154 - 20s - loss: 3.1491e-04 - val_loss: 0.0039 - 20s/epoch - 1ms/step
Epoch 10/20
14154/14154 - 19s - loss: 3.1466e-04 - val_loss: 0.0039 - 19s/epoch - 1ms/step
Epoch 11/20
14154/14154 - 20s - loss: 3.1495e-04 - val_loss: 0.0043 - 20s/epoch - 1ms/step
Epoch 12/20
14154/14154 - 20s - loss: 3.1078e-04 - val_loss: 0.0049 - 20s/epoch - 1ms/step
Epoch 13/20
14154/14154 - 18s - loss: 3.1250e-04 - val_loss: 0.0044 - 18s/epoch - 1ms/step
Epoch 14/20
14154/14154 - 19s - loss: 3.1094e-04 - val_loss: 0.0034 - 19s/epoch - 1ms/step
Epoch 15/20
14154/14154 - 18s - loss: 3.0000e-04 - val_loss: 0.0034 - 18s/epoch - 1ms/step
Epoch 16/20
14154/14154 - 19s - loss: 2.9751e-04 - val_loss: 0.0041 - 19s/epoch - 1ms/step
Epoch 17/20
14154/14154 - 18s - loss: 3.0442e-04 - val_loss: 0.0030 - 18s/epoch - 1ms/step
Epoch 18/20
14154/14154 - 19s - loss: 3.0559e-04 - val_loss: 0.0034 - 19s/epoch - 1ms/step
Epoch 19/20
14154/14154 - 20s - loss: 3.0896e-04 - val_loss: 0.0036 - 20s/epoch - 1ms/step
Epoch 20/20
14154/14154 - 21s - loss: 2.9588e-04 - val_loss: 0.0037 - 21s/epoch - 1ms/step

Train Score: 3.79 RMSE
Test Score: 14.37 RMSE
```

What is wrong?? I see it as underfitting...how can I fix this?

Comment: I would not describe this as underfitting since the model is still able to learn patterns within the data leading to a small loss. The validation loss being quite high relative to the training loss (roughly 10 times as large) would indicate overfitting to me. Given the fact that the training loss is already much lower early on in the training phase I would try to decrease the capacity of the model (i.e. decreasing the number of parameters).

Comment: What do you mean by saying "decreasing the number of parameters"?

Comment: Simply use a smaller/simpler model that has less parameters that can be adjusted during the training phase.

Comment: Ok, I fixed it. What cannot understand is why in the first epoch is high (0.008) and from the second epoch goes to 0.001. What is wrong?

Comment: That does not necessarily mean that something is wrong, to me it seems like the model starts out quite random (leading to a high loss) but is quickly able to learn the patterns from the data, allowing it to reach a low loss after just a few epochs.

Comment: As I can imagine someone can understand the under/over fitting by loss graph (validation, training) . Can someone understand by the graph of the variable? For instance  if I train temperature in time-series (y=temperature, x=time-series), can he understand it from the plot?